# make libre office calc stop converting columns in to formulas

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have columns in a csv like this:

```
 "== 1:D2410, == 2:D2420"
```

When I import them with libre calc it turns them in to this:

```
 == A1:D2410, == A2:D2420
```

Which is horrible. These are not mathematical formulas. How do I turn this off? I have deselected every option under 'tools:options', 'tools:cell contents' I have tried importing as a .txt and trying to force any options that pop-up. Nothing..

Answer (score 0):

When you open the csv file with LibreOffice, the "Text Import" dialog will pop up.  (If you do not get the "Text Import" dialog, please describe exactly how you are opening the file so we can point you to a different method.)  The bold heading third from the top is "Other Options".  Under this heading, check the box for "Quoted fields as text".  Then press "OK" to accept the import filter selections.  Now it will import your quoted fields as text.

Comment: Unfortunately that option did not seem to work either... I ended up installing Open Office. The idea behind this being - the older version would have a working version of 'quoted fields as text' option. Which it did! I think it may be a bug.. But I dont have time to investigate it further